finding a basis for an elementary abelian $p$-group with GAP
Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$
such that $\overline{G}=\displaystyle\frac{G}{N}$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^s, s\geq 1$.
(For example we could suppose that $N=\Phi(G)$).
I want to find a basis $B:=\{\overline{g_1},\overline{g_2},\dots,\overline{g_s}\}$
for $\frac{G}{N}$, where $\langle g_i\rangle \ntriangleleft G$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,s\}$.
Does there exists an algorithm in GAP to obtain such a basis?
Thanks in advance!

A polycyclic generating set does for its elementary abelian layers exactly what you want. You thus want to use modpcgs:=ModuloPcgs(G,N);
You then can use ExponentsOfPcElement and PcElementByExponents to translate between elements of $G$ and exponent vectors.
For example:
gap> G:=TransitiveGroup(4,3);N:=Centre(G);
D(4)
Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ])
gap> modpcgs:=ModuloPcgs(G,N);
Pcgs([ (2,4), (1,2,3,4) ])
gap> ExponentsOfPcElement(modpcgs,(1,4)(2,3));
[ 1, 1 ]
gap> PcElementByExponents(modpcgs,[1,1]);
(1,2)(3,4)
gap> (1,4)(2,3)/(1,2)(3,4) in N;
true


Dear ahulpke, many thanks for your exact and nice answer!
